# Classifying multivariate data as gaussian, non-gaussian, or a mixture of gaussians?

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption, curve-fitting

It's for the following use case:

I have a set of "detects" of a group of individual targets (mostly stationary) that I wish to cluster or segment such that each cluster (group of detects) represents an individual target. These clusters are sparse enough, and the noise in the location estimates are low enough, that a simple DBSCAN is mostly sufficient for this process. However some of these clusters span wide enough as to cause suspicion. After plotting these clusters I find that they fit into three categories.

[image]

I would like to classify these accordingly using some algorithm. I was thinking about conducting a normality test and if it passes then classifying it as Stationary with high noise and if it doesn't run a GMM model on it gradually increasing the number of clusters until an optimal silhouette score is achieved, and if the GMM's yield gaussians with extremely narrow distributions then classify it as moving (picture 1) other wise as multiple-stationary. I imagine there is a more efficient way however and I'm not even sure if my method will work. So I was also wondering if there is a simple way to classify them as gaussian, non-gaussian, or a mixture of gaussians, as technically the moving target one is not best explained by a gaussian or GMM model.

Comment: The Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) is the spline of the distribution world.  There is a theorem that says in the limit of lots of samples any distribution can be approximated as a GMM.  GMM is faster when seeded with a pathological version of itself (kmeans).  If you are trying to connect detects with models, then the Kalman Filter and its derivatives might work for you.